# I need help showing the continuity of two functions in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

firstly function defined as $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix}\rightarrow 
\   \left\{
\begin{array}{}
      \frac{x_1^2-x_2^2}{x_1^2+x_2^2} & \text{if } \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix} \\
      0 & \text{if } \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{array} 
\right. \ $$
I want to show that $f$ is not continuous at $0$ but haven't exactly found a method, I was initially motivated by the fact that the function $g:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix}\rightarrow 
\   \left\{
\begin{array}{}
      \frac{x_1x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2} & \text{if } \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix} \\
      0 & \text{if } \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{array} 
\right. \ $$ is discontinuous at $0$ but as I haven't been able to prove it via a similar method help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can you not have proved it "via a similar method"? The identical method works. This makes your "effort" very suspect, and this is why we suggest that you post your efforts and not just ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove a function $f$ is discontinuous at a point $x_0\in\mathcal D(f)$ you need only show  that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\neq f(x_0)$.

Here, you are proving $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\neq 0$$

Suppose the limit is $0$. Then it must hold that for ***any*** continuous function $y(x)$ such that $y(0)=0$, we have: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2-y(x)^2}{x^2+y(x)^2}=0$$

Test some simple functions for $y$ and you'll find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens if $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\x_2 \end{pmatrix}$ approaches $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ along the line $x_1=x_2$ and along the line $x_2=0.$ The limits differ from each other.